# How do we know that graphs have the shapes they do?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

This is a pretty simple question I think, but I don't know how to answer it.

For example, we all know that a parabola such as y=x^2 looks something like this:
[parabola](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCwv4.gif)

But my question is, how do we know that the graph actually looks like this? We can't actually plot out an infinite amount of points to see that the graph follows a smooth pattern, but instead we can only individually plot points and we just connect them. Why do we just assume that the points can be connected?

If anyone needs any clarification about my question, feel free to ask.

Comment: We know the graph is continuous.

Comment: That's because we've proved that the curve/function is `continuous` and `smooth` (i.e. its derivative is continuous).

Answer (score 4):

Continuity and smoothness aren't really enough by themselves to be certain that we've drawn a given graph correctly: maybe in the interval $(17.123487634827631, 17.123487634827632)$ there's a huge spike! We wouldn't see this just by plotting a bunch of points unless by sheer dumb luck we picked one in that interval, so how can we rule it out?

To rule this out, we analyze the function. For example, we can prove that on positive reals, the function $f(x)=x^2$ is increasing; this rules out such a spike, because "half" the spike would have to be *decreasing* (think about it). Similarly we can figure out how fast $f$ can ever increase, in any interval (that is, we can find the maximum of the derivative of $f$), and so forth. Perhaps the most useful fact about $f$ in terms of graphing it is that $f$ is **convex**: if we let $L$ be the line connecting $(a, f(a))$ to $(b, f(b))$ (for $a<b$), the graph of $f$ on $(a, b)$ lies *below* the line $L$. This gives a *lot* of information about what the graph looks like! And this fact can be proved from the basic properties of the real numbers.

More complicated properties of graphs (e.g. being "steeper" over here than over there) can be precisely defined and verified using *calculus*. In the end, these facts can give us a very complete picture of what the graph of $f$ looks like.

Answer (score 0):

In the particular case for the parabola, it is a conic section, so you can obtain its shape by imagining the intersection between a cone and a plane.